# How to get value of Tkinter scale without need to click on Button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How to get value of Tkinter scale without need to click on a Button?

My code below work fine... but I need way to get value without needing to click the Button that automatically changes value when I move the Tkinter scale bar.

```
from tkinter import *

def sel():
   selection = "Value = " + str(var.get())
   label.config(text = selection)

root = Tk()
var = DoubleVar()
scale = Scale( root, variable = var )
scale.pack(anchor=CENTER)

button = Button(root, text="Get Scale Value", command=sel)
button.pack(anchor=CENTER)

label = Label(root)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you aware that the `Scale` widget accepts a `command` option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `command` option in the `Scale` object:

```
from tkinter import *

def sel(val=0):  # pass new scale value
   #selection = "Value = " + str(var.get())
   #label.config(text = selection)
   label.config(text = val)

root = Tk()
var = DoubleVar()
scale = Scale( root, variable = var, command=sel)  # call sel function on change
scale.pack(anchor=CENTER)

button = Button(root, text="Get Scale Value", command=sel)
button.pack(anchor=CENTER)

label = Label(root)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a textvariable instead text argument:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

var = DoubleVar()
scale = Scale( root, variable = var )
scale.pack(anchor=CENTER)

label = Label(root, textvariable=var)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```